# Can I edit/change the package name for my project in Huawei AppGallery Connect later on?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I just realized I misspelled my package name while creating the project in AppGallery Connect. Is there a way to modify it back so I can correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

package name can be only entered once during application creation and cannot be changed later. So I suggest you to create a new application in AppGallery Connect with a correct package name and move everything to there.